# Sort specific objects

Tags: vb.net

I have tree classes as follows:

```
Public Class HtmlSection
        Property Name As String
        Property SubSections As List(Of HtmlSubSection)
End Class

Public Class HtmlSubSection
        Property Name As String
        Property SelectedSentences As List(Of HtmlSentence)
End Class

Public Class HtmlSentence
        Property Sentence As String
        Property Position As Integer   
End Class
```

In below method i am searching for all sentences for each subsection belonging to specific section, at the end i sort those records by Position asc. However sometimes positions have to be changed (directly in sentences) because there could be gaps means after i do OrderBy it will be ordered but it could look like this below. Is there any easy way like linq to change that Positions of that sentences to avoid gaps let's say in the method i shown below.

```
2
5
77
1001
```

i would like to change positions starting from 0 in our example:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Method:

```
Public Function GetSelectedSentencesOnSectionLevel(section As HtmlSection) As List(Of HtmlSentence)
     Dim sentencesList As New List(Of HtmlSentence)
       For Each exSection As HtmlSection In _htmlFactory.SectionsList
        If exSection.Name = section.Name Then
           Dim sentencesList As New List(Of HtmlSentence)
             If Not IsNothing(exSection.SubSections) Then
                For Each exSubsection As HtmlSubSection In exSection.SubSections
                  If Not IsNothing(exSubsection.SelectedSentences) Then
                    For Each exSentence As HtmlSentence In exSubsection.SelectedSentences
                           sentencesList.Add(exSentence)
                    Next
                  End If
                Next
             End If
        End If       
    Next

'sort sentences by Posiions ascending
sentencesList = sentencesList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Position).ToList()            
 Return sentencesList
End Function
```

**EDIT : more code for helpers:**

global class:

```
Public Class HtmlFactory
        Property SectionsList As List(Of HtmlSection)

        Sub New()
            SectionsList = New List(Of HtmlSection)
        End Sub

        Sub New(pSectionsList As List(Of HtmlSection))
            _SectionsList = pSectionsList
        End Sub

        Public Sub AddSection(section As HtmlSection)
            SectionsList.Add(section)
        End Sub
....
```

Comment: What is the collection you're working on?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev what do you mean, everything above.

Comment: I mean that you cannot determine what is the subsection of a sentence, if you have just `List(Of HtmlSentence)`... Where `exSection` does come from?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev I've added more code for you. I would appreciate separated method to correct Positions numbers to remove gaps but keep the order as in example and use it in shown method and other places when i need it. Remember this is only for specific section i pass.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a pure LINQ solution.

```
Dim index As Integer = -1

Dim sectionName As String

Dim allTheSections As List(Of HtmlSection)

Dim sentenceList = allTheSections _
    .Where(Function(sect) _
               sect.SubSections IsNot Nothing _
               AndAlso sect.Name.Equals(sectionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) _
    .SelectMany(Function(sect) sect.SubSections) _
    .Where(Function(subSect) subSect.SelectedSentences IsNot Nothing) _
    .SelectMany(Function(subSect) subSect.SelectedSentences) _
    .OrderBy(Function(ss) ss.Position) _
    .Select(Function(ss)
                index += 1
                Return New HtmlSentence With {.Position = index, .Sentence = ss.Sentence}
            End Function) _
    .ToList()
```

In this example, `allTheSections` is where you `exSection` does coming from.

Comment: So should i pass List(Of HtmlSections) to allTheSections variable and then to sectionName variable should i pass name of the section i want to play with and then your linq will change Positions counting from 0 (keeping the current order-that's important) and keep rest as it was in collection? Is that all true?

Comment: Right. But if you want the counting to start from 0, you need to initialize the `index` to -1. I.e. `Dim index As Integer = -1`

Comment: I modified a bit your code and added ss.Position = index after line  index += 1 because i want also save new positions into oryginal collection. However there is one problem your code is not taking care about current order of positions... For example if before we got e.g: for Sentence_1 pos was = 99 for Sentence_2 pos was 6 and for Sentence_3 pos was 3 so it should be finally: Sentence_1 pos = 3 Sentence_2 pos 2 Sentence_3 pos 1. Hope you get my point. You can use testing code: https://pastebin.com/XU9UvDR0

Comment: Got you. In that case, just move the `OrderBy` statement just before the last `Select` statement; I've corrected my answer...

Comment: seems that works perfectly, however what would be the diffrence if i would additionaly at the end add: .OrderBy(Function(n) n.Position).ToList() i do not see any diffrence when adding that why?

Comment: @Dino Because the sentences are already sorted by `Position`, using original values. That last `Select` just constructs new sentences, filling new values - i.e. `index` - in the `Position` property, AFTER the sentences are sorted using the previous values. So adding `OrderBy(Function (n) n.Position)` to the end is void.

Comment: there is one more thing unofrtunetly Bozhidar. There could be a situation that sect doesn't contain sect.Subsections - means sec.SubSections could be Nothing then we have to exit your code. And other one could be that sect.SubSections is not nothing means containing something but for specific/s subSect.SelectedSentences of specific sect.SubSection could be nothing , then we have to go next subSect.SelectedSentences ... Hope you get my point. It is shown in my oryginal post 2x If Not IsNothing(exSection.SubSections) and the other one: if Not IsNothing(exSubsection.SelectedSentences) Then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154012/discussion-between-bozhidar-stoinev-and-dino).

Comment: would appreciate this last change.